# exec() not changing attrib of a file outside of current folder

Tags: php, windows, cmd

The `exec()` function works for changing file attributes in Windows machine as long as the path given is inside the development folder. Like

D:\Programs\Development\www\

as long as the file is within that path it's attributes  can change.

```
$path = D:\Programs\Development\www\test.jpg
exec("attrib +s +h $path");
```

That works, but once I change the path to somewhere else this function doesn't seem to work

```
$path = 'D:\Desktop\New Folder (2)\Test Folders\test.jpg'
exec("attrib +s +h $path");
```

Now the same command won't work. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the path in quotes.

As with most operating systems, spaces in file names is a problem you have to deal with head on. This is typically done with backslashes, however, since Windows uses backslashes for its folder system, you will need to use quotes.

```
$path = 'D:\Desktop\New Folder (2)\Test Folders\test.jpg'
exec("attrib +s +h \"{$path}\"");
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thank you Q. Sheets. I had a feeling it was something like that. I had my doubts that it could have been windows escaping it.